# Adding example based on a schema

Tags: swagger, openapi

Say I have a schema that describes the value returned by an API call. The schema contains complex objects that have their own schema, for example: an object called 'interfaces'. Is there a way to get swagger UI to generate an example for the 'interfaces' field based on the Interface schema?

```
interfaces:
  description: A list of the device's interfaces
  type: array
  items:
    type: object
    required: true
    schema: 
      $ref: '#components/schemas/Interface'
    example: #<---- What should I put here?
  required: true

Interface:
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      description: Interface's name
      type: string
      required: true
      example: eth0
    IP:
     ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get Swagger to generate an example"? Swagger is not a single tool, but a collective name for [several tools](https://swagger.io/tools/) - Swagger UI, Swagger Codegen, etc. Which of these tools is your question about?

Comment: I would like to see the example in the UI, so I guess it would be swagger UI. I'm using swagger UI express npm package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation throughly, it appears that OpenAPI 3.0 supports definition of common examples that can be reused across the API documentation yaml files. See example in the "Reusing Examples" section in the following [link](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/).

Answer (score 0):

In the example you should put the expected value of primitive variable or object. Say, if the USERNAME variable type is string, the example could be "exampleuser190". If ID is of integer type, then example could be "845" or smth similar. It's up to you waht to put in the example, but try to be precise in order to represent real situation and variable structure in API.

So, don't use simple example as "5" if expected value is 12 digit long, with two zeros ahead, like this one "003454534546" or some complicated key for usernames, etc.

In your case I would put example into Interfaces schema or put expected object example (how it looks like):

```
interfaces:
  description: A list of the device's interfaces
  type: array
  items:
    type: object
    required: true
    schema: 
      $ref: '#components/schemas/Interface'
  required: true

components:
  schemas:
   Interface:
     variableXX:
       type: integer
       example: 34534
```

Comment: I added examples to the interface schema, but I still does not show them in the device. Since the interface schema is quite long, and I'd like to reuse it in other places I don't want to manually insert an example in the device schema.